# How do you add the Python.h libraries to eclipse for use in a C++ program?

Tags: python, c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm relatively new to using eclipse, and I'm trying to figure out how to use the Python.h includes that are described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#). What steps do I need to take to get eclipse to properly compile that include? Thanks!

Edit:
I am using Windows if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure PyDev is installed as a plug-in. 
You can do this by selecting `Help>Install New Software`
you will then select add and choose a name (eg. PyDev), 
then enter `http://pydev.org/updates` as a location.
You will then select `PyDev` from the list of available software and accept the license, and trust the certificate. 
You may need to restart Eclipse afterwards.

You can refer to this [Official Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) for additional information on embedding and extending your code.

Comment: I followed your steps, and PyDev now appears installed in `Windows->Preferences`, but the error messages still persist. Am I missing anything? PyDev appears in the list on the left side. Thanks

Comment: @FairlyFactual could you post the error message here.

Comment: eclipse gives the error message on `#include <Python.h>` as `Unresolved inclusion: <Python.h>`

Comment: Okay. I was messing around with my program a little in an attempt to fix the problem and eventually just decided to replace `<Python.h>` with `"C:\...Python.h"`, and the program started to work. I guess the problem was to do with eclipse not being able to find the include even though I installed it through the `Help>Install New Software` method.

Comment: @FairlyFactual always ensure your header files can be accessed during compiling.  So include the header file path like you did and it saves you from some nasty linker errors

Comment: @FairlyFactual Just curious was your error message something like: `error: header.h: No file or directory found.`?

Comment: the error was just `Unresolved inclusion: <Python.h>` and nothing else. I thought it was rather strange that it didn't tell me anything about the source file not being located.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to

- install the PyDev plug-in
- edit the project properties [[link]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/setting-up-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another quite simple solution:

- Install Python for Windows (download it from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/)).
- Reference its `include` directory (in my case `C:\Programs\Python36\include`) in your project (Project Properties - C/C++ General - Paths and Symbols - Includes - GNU C++ - Add…).